# why 'col-md-6' giving too much gaps in middle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display 4 div's side by side with bootstrap classes but unfortunately, I was getting too many spaces in the middle(right side to each div) and also not aligned to center. I want them to be center-aligned with very little space in middle. Please help.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.2.0/css/all.css">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <style>
     .student-blocks {
       padding: 1rem;
       box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
       max-width: 9rem;
       text-align: center;
     }
   </style>
   <body>
      <section>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="student-blocks">
                           <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                           <p>Students</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="student-blocks">
                           <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                           <p>Students</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="student-blocks">
                           <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                           <p>Students</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="student-blocks">
                           <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                           <p>Students</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing the opening `html` and `body` tags in this, could you fix those? Then, if you want the 1000+ and students to be on the same line, change the `<p>` to `<span>`. Paragraphs are block elements. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/fL6v2y1b/2/ and then elaborate about the problem a bit more.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: I am able to arrange them in a row but gaps are coming.That's what my problem. please resolve.

Comment: Your sample code looks correct, Running the code snippet results 4 items side by side (2 per row).
Maybe add a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: It has to do with your screen size, please check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Take a screenshot, and just mark this 'gap' you're talking about. Because currently the output is what it should be. So your requirement needs to be a little clearer.

Comment: Please check the result in full window. I want those all div's to be aligned to center and very less space on right side of each div.

Comment: I know that col-md is talking about medium screen devices but I've no idea what this "col-6" exactly means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kind of re-worked your HTML a bit to get your desired result. In order to get them on the same line, I changed them to `.col-3` to span across the default 12 columns per line. 12/3 = 4 per line. You can simply put this onto a new line by putting the desired `col` sizes back to `col-6` for two per line etc..

I added a `flex display` to your container and `justify-content: center` so that everything is centered.

```css
.student-blocks {
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
  max-width: 9rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* change padding to change spacing */

div.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.2.0/css/all.css">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <section>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can simply change the `padding` on your CSS selector `div.col-6` to change the spacing to what you desire.

To eliminate spacing just simply make the `padding: 0;` like so:

```css
.student-blocks {
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
  max-width: 9rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.2.0/css/all.css">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <section>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3">
                  <div class="student-blocks">
                     <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                     <p>Students</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want this to be done by bootstrap classes completely. I already worked on flexbox and got the desired results.

Comment: @Gopichand Okay then delete the `container` and `div.col-3` **styles** but STILL use my HTML.  Then just set your `max-width: 100%;` --> you're getting those gaps because you have set a max-width property in a container that's larger than your max-width style. You can adjust the `max-width: 100%;` as you wish which is what will change your spacing. Start at 100% for no gaps and then down to 90% for slight gaps, etc... Either way, you're going to have to rework your HTML, you have a row which is fine but then you have another row inside that parent row class that isn't even functioning as a row

Comment: @Gopichand If you don't understand Bootstrap all that much I can put notes into my version of your HTML and explain what everything means.

Comment: So glad. Please give me some notes about must use bootstrap classes if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to place 4 div's side by side in a single row then please try below template.

```
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

            <div class="col">
              <div class="student-blocks">
                <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                <p>Students</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="student-blocks">
                <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                <p>Students</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
              <div class="student-blocks">
                <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                <p>Students</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="student-blocks">
                <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span><small>1000+</small></span>
                <p>Students</p>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: No change in output.